ESP32: Random restarts, probably due to voltage instabilities
I created a module with an ESP32-S3-WROOM-1-N16R8 powered via a MCP1825S LDO. The power supply is a Mean Well with 5 V / 4 A which also powers a Raspberry Pi 4.
There are two interesting things:

If I use a 20x5 mm fuse with 250 mA, the ESP32 will restart multiple times until it finally connects to Wi-Fi. According to the specsheet (p. 18) the Wi-Fi module has a peak of up to 355 mA at 3.3 V. This corresponds to 234 mA at 5 V. This is very tight, so I think a fuse with 315 mA (for 5 V) is a good solution. With this size it starts normaly.

However, even with a 500 mA (for 5 V) fuse I encountered following issue: After a few days the module was running fine it suddenly started to restart from time to time and sometimes almost endlessly. I don't think the Mean Well can be the reason, because there is planty of room. The Raspberry Pi 4 acts only as a Pi-Hole, so there were multiple amperes left only for my module.


I have attached a 3D model of my PCB. Is there something obviously wrong with it? I do not use a capacitor for the 5 V line. If suggested, where should I place it optimally?




I'd suggest some bulk capacitance on the 5V line where it enters the board to compensate for supply cable inductance. Are those 3 black rectangles relais? If so, some bulk capacitance on their supply line wouldn't hurt.

Thanks for the advice! Yes, these are relais (even though the restarts do not have to do with the relais, if they are totally without current the ESP32 still restarts).

Since you’ve used a linear regulator, the 5V current is the same as the 3V3 current. No constant wattage as with a switching regulator. The 10uF cap might not be sized correctly - you need to consider the voltage derating spec of ceramic caps. Your schematic shows it as a polarized cap, which it is not. The fuse is a waste of time - what is it protecting? If anything, it should be at the point of power distribution. A transzorb would’ve been a useful addition  for some input transient protection. There’s also a number of dubious routing issues. Time for Rev B methinks.

The 5V power supply delivers up to 4A, so I thought it would make sense to add a fuse. The 10uF capacitor is a X5R with 16V, so there should be no DC bias problem. You say there are dubious routing issues, do you have an example?

To check for power supply issues, you can use a scope and probe 5V and 3V3 while the ESP32 draws pulsed current. The worst case for supply current is when transmitting over WiFi so you can use that, for example make the ESP32 serve a webpage to make sure it does transmit enough. Then check the scope, set the trigger to record when input voltage drops by say 0.2V, and hit the web page with a browser. This way even if the ESP32 crashes the scope will have recorded it.
According to this link, current peaks during wifi transmission can reach close to 0.8A so I have doubts about your 500mA LDO.
Thus you should check with the scope, using two channels, both on the 5V input and the 3V3 output. Fuses have quite a lot of resistance, and you have a diode in series, so the problem could be on the input.
If you see the input voltage dropping then squeezing the LDO into dropout and bringing down output voltage, then you need more capacitance on the input, like a few hundred µF low ESR electrolytic cap. If input voltage remains good, well above say 4V, leaving a good margin for the LDO, but you still see the output voltage dropping, then it would be the LDO limiting current.
Most ESP32 boards use AMS1117 which is specified at 0.8A, but this is an obsolete part with slow transient response, and it will also cause problems on large supply current steps, notably when the ESP comes out of sleep, so I don't recommend it.
Usually I use LDL1117 to replace AMS1117, which solves all these problems. It's an excellent LDO, but its pinout is not compatible with your board.
As a stopgap, before changing the LDO, you can put a few hundred µF low ESR electrolytic cap on the output. Note in the datasheet, they do say "stable with 1µF ceramic" but the transient response curves are taken with much higher capacitance. With less capacitance, transient response will be worse. How much is impossible to say without measuring.
Due to its spiky current during WiFi transmission, ESP32 really needs the 10µF ceramic decoupling cap. High-ESR caps like tantalum do not work well. So if you use another LDO, you need one with compatible pinout, say 1A current, stable with 10µF output ceramic cap, and fast transient response.

Thank you! I don't have yet a oscilloscope, but I will buy one :)

I now bought an oscilloscope and made some tests. It looks normal to me, so I think in this case I have an EMV or EMI issue or so.
